# Rails controller and routes configuration for website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have an application in RAILS, it is composed of a set of API, a basic website, and an admin dashboard. 
For the API routing I have no problems, as they belong to a model and a controller and are compliant with the RAILS RESTful pattern (a controller for each model, and a method for each HTTP method).

What I'm not comfortable with is writing routes and controllers for website. 
The main website is at / so the default route is `root :to => "home#index"`and I have
Routes for the website pages which look like

```
 get "home/index"
  get "map/index"
  get "api/index"
  get "cgu/index"
  get "legal/index"
```

Which I think it is not good, as I have a controller per view and I need to define a get for each views. 
Now for the dashboard I tried a different approach. 
It is at /dashboard, the default route is   `match "dashboard" => "dashboard#index"` and here is few pages as an examples

```
 get "dashboard/index"
  get "dashboard/users"
  get "dashboard/users_stats"
  get "dashboard/routes"
  get "dashboard/routes_stats"
  get "dashboard/charts"
  get "dashboard/financial"
```

So for the dashboard I have a massive dashboard_controller, which contains a `def method` for each dashboard pages. IE:

```
#dashboard/users
  def users
     @users = User.all

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :layout => 'dashboard'}
    end
  end
```

the controller of the dashboard is at /controller but for views and assets I have put it in /folder/dashboard/

Here is 2 questions:

- What is the best way to build the home website and dashboard ? Should I have a controller per page or a global controller where I have a method per pages ? (Which I find very convenient, less code).
- How should I organize my routes to avoid to set a get "something/something" for each page ? 
  Or it is normal with RAILS that I have a route defined for each of my page ? I'm fairly new.

EDIT: 
To clarify, the dashboard is built around an existing application with API that follow RESTFul Rails pattern:

```
  resources :users
  resources :routes
```

But the dashboard is not tied to any existing resources, it only do stats about those resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have custom controller action names, then yes, you'll need to define every route.  If you use Restful routes, then you can define them easily as

```
resources :users
```

which will automatically create routes for actions:  index, show, edit, update, create and destroy.

This might be helpful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

For your dashboard, which probably is bringing together a lot of resources, so they'll probably be custom methods. I'd suggest focusing on building your app by individual resource. Then, once you've defined them all, build your dashboard.

Comment: Yes, the dashboard does not depend of RESTful routes, as I don't tied it to a specific model. It is query on existing resources and models to build stats.

Answer (score 0):

check [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) out if you haven't;

I think you haven't embraced the MVC concept of Rails.

For example, say you have "users". You should have users_controller.rb, users.rb (model), /views/users (view) under the app directory.

users_controller contains the index, show, create, etc default actions and your custom actions like stats

user.rb contains instance/static/helper methods

/views/users/ contains templates that corresponds to actions in the controller.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to follow RESTful routes with my dashboard, It only use get, no date manipulation, not tied to any model. Stats on existing date, resources and models.

Comment: for this i think you just make a controller/views without model; the controller contains only custom actions. But it shouldn't be too large, if it is, then probably some actions should be resources.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything that other people have said here. You should definitely try to be more RESTful and create more routes like this:

```
 resources :users
```

However, there is usually a controller that is not RESTful (usually called pages or static) that serves pages such as `Privacy`, `About Us`, etc, etc. For those routes, I usually do this:

```
['api', 'privacy', 'us'].each do |p|
  get p, :controller => 'pages', :action => p
 end
```

Comment: Great idea. Might make the routes less obvious, but the brevity sure makes for a short routes.rb.